# How to scan a paragraph for hashtags and put them in an array in Javascript/ AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For example:
  Lorem #ipsum dolor sit #amet

Using a regex how do i take #ipsum and #amet and put them into an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
/#\w+/g
```

To get each word with a hashtag. Note you can use `*` instead of `+` if you also want to match the hashtags themselves. Then you can use [`.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), which will return an array of the matched items. For example:

```js
var reg = /#\w+/g;
console.log("Lorem #ipsum dolor sit #amet".match(reg));
```

Note: `\w` will match word characters (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`), if you want any text other than whitespace use `\S` instead.